# How do I use timer or get today's date when suspended iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'd like to let my app detect date even when iOS app is suspended(neither foreground nor background).

Can app use timer or function which get date in the suspended state?

This question may be simple question, but I couldn't find answer on the web.

Please let me know it is possible or not.

[Edit]
 I want to run specified code at tomorrow midnight whenever app is any status.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What exactly to you want to achieve by checking the date? Maybe there is a bypass...

Comment: yes, I want to run specified code at tomorrow midnight whenever app is any status.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible (I may be wrong). The only timed task I know can be done is local notifications.

Comment: Oh, and if it's maintenence task, you can do it using background fetch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is OS X programming, but maybe you can adapt it.

So setup a timer:

```
var timer:NSTimer? = NSTimer(timeInterval:30.0, target: self, selector: "timeCheck:", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer!, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop().addTimer(timer!, forMode: NSEventTrackingRunLoopMode)
```

This sets up a timer to fire every 30 seconds.  Then what happens when the timer fires:

```
func timeCheck(timer:UnsafePointer<NSTimer>)
{
    let date = NSDate()
    let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
    let components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay , fromDate: date)

    let year = components.year
    let month = components.month
    let day = components.day

    // Do something with this

    println("Today is \(day), \(month), \(year)")
}
```

This prints:

Today is 24, 12, 2014

Every 30 seconds.